# What is the syntax for a Maven parameter of type String[]

Tags: maven, syntax, parameter-passing, arrays

For example the [annotationProcessors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessors) parameter in the Maven Compiler Plugin needs a String[] as a parameter.

What is the syntax for a String Array in Maven?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Off the top of my head arrays are handled this way:

```
<annotationProcessors>
    <annotationProcessor>com.example.AP1</annotationProcessor>
    <annotationProcessor>com.example.AP2</annotationProcessor>
</annotationProcessors>
```

(an old [post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201012.mbox/%3CAANLkTimijzkLB3xgd1-BUZiK-mchqpRYrO_OS_gy8tuk@mail.gmail.com%3E) on the apache maven-users mailing list supports this).

Comment: How is this different from type List<String>? And, does it really matter if the key is the singular form of the outer xml element, or can it be anything?